# Calculation of daily distance

Tags: qgis

I have 3 collared animals and their GPS position is mostly daily recorded, included information about the date, time, longitude, latitude. The daily records vary from any record for weeks to 24 records per day. I manually reduced records for 3 records per day as much standardized as possible. I would like to know how to calculate the daily average distance they have traveled even though the data are very unbalanced.
I am using QGIS 2.18.12.

Comment: Hi and welcome to GIS SE! Could you please provide an example of your data?

Comment: If your data lives in a database, the last 3 records per day can be limited using database functions, and the distances can be applied between those records easily enough. I assume also the animals each have their own INDIVIDUAL_ID type of column as well? I'm afraid if you're using shapefiles, you will be limited to the tools available for processing shapefiles. A database such as postgresql with the postgis extension is best suited for this application.

Comment: Hello!  I would propose that you convert your points to lines.  Once you have lines, you will have their distance.  I recommend the QGIS plugin "Points to Paths", with the Line per Vertex checked on.  With it, you can create a separate line per day, and each line will have multiple time segments.  The plugin is experimental, but I've had good success with it.

Comment: Thank you for all the suggestion. Just to clarify the data, there is an example generated by the software for collecting data: 1st column RECORD_ID ("1", "2", "3", for each animal one number, I think it is useless info. 2nd column COLAR_ID ("3037" ,"3038, "3040"), 3th column DATATIME (format-01.11.2018 13:03), 4th LATITUDE, 5th LONGITUDE. Then I try to have at least three points per day 0:00, 13:00, 23:00, but not in all cases is possible and sometimes I have one or none.

Comment: I tried to convert points to lines. For a "Group features by" I selected collar ID, When I choose DATETIME, there is some error. When I looked on the attribute table did according to collar ID it does not make sense. I probably must manually change the base dataset.